# docker error when called from network

Tags: jenkins, docker

to deploy our system, we use a docker-compose.yml file. It works fine on local and remote machines working through SSH, and machines deploys correctly. The problem is when docker is launched from jenkins machine on the a slave machine, I get this error:

Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

```
If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
Building node
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

If I include 'whoami' in my script, it returns the same user I use in local deploys, so it doesn't seem a problem with permissions.
I found a workaround by using 'sudo' but I don't like the solution, because I don't want to insert 'sudo' clauses in my scripts. The problem could be in the way remote access get the socket, but I couldn't find it

Comment: You need to elevate the user `jenkins` to be able to contact Docker engine.

Comment: I think jenkins is unrelated. Whoami returns 'ubuntu' user and jenkins access to this machine throught java agent.

Comment: Restart jenkins in that case. Or run the id command inside your terminal and on your build to see a difference. I remember now that I just needed to reboot jenkins